# No puedo conectarme a expo.io desde mi celular

Tags: react-native

Hola recién estoy aprendiendo React Native ya que no puedo configurar android studio uso EXPO.IO pero tengo un problema con Expo para  visualizar la app en mi celular con la APP Cliente de Expo, me aparece el siguiente error, he buscado en google alguna solución pero nada.
En la cosola no tengo errores escaneo el codigo QR pero me sale este error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes mejorar la pregunta, mostrar los errores que te muestra la consola o algún fragmento de código relacionado si desea recibir ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes estar conectado a la misma red Wifi que el ordenador que esta ejecutando Expo XDE, ya que este está a modo de servidor.

Si quieres probar tu app fuera de la red Wifi, debes configurar Expo XDE como Tunnel en lugar de Lan o Localhost

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez realices este cambio, haz click en Restart y vuelve a enviarlo al dispositivo o a abrirlo con código QR desde la App de tu dispositivo.

Comment: David Cantón debo instalar XDE? pensé que solamente con Expo Cliente app en mi android era suficiente

Comment: XDE es la representación gráfica del comando react-native run-android, te lo recomiendo, pruébalo y nos cuentas